# How to hide "Change role to" dropdown on Users admin menu

Tags: users, user-roles, dropdown

[image]

How can I hide the "**Change role to**" dropdown?

Comment: If you just want to hide it on screen, i.e. visually, then you can use CSS, e.g. `select#new_role { display: none }`. But, why are you hiding it?

Comment: Even if you hide it there, it can still be changed when you drill-down to the individual user.

Comment: @Sally CJ, I remember that I've done things like that before on the post.php page. So, thank you for suggesting this.

Comment: @vancoder Actually, I'll custom individual user page too, let me know if I did wrong things.